# Python3 import module without relative path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have a folder test with the following py files

```
mytest/
- test.py
- utility.py
- pb2.py
- pb2_grpc.py
```

pb2 and pb2_grpc are generated by python grpc tool.

in test.py, there are

```
import utility
import pb2
import pb2_grpc
```

in pb2_grpc.py, there is

```
import pb2
```

When I cd to mytest directory and execute

```
python -m unittest test.py
```

everything is fine. But now I need to execute the test in the parent directory, then I encountered "no module named" error when I did

```
python -m unittest mytest/test.py
```

Then I changed `import utility` to `from . import utility`, it works. But for those auto generated files, I could not edit them.

The only way I can do now is to add `os.append.path(os.path.dirname(__file__))` in my test.py, then when pb2_grpc is invoked, it knows where to find pb2. But is there a better way to do that?

Comment: you can edit import in generated protobuf files

Answer (score 0):

alot of relative import issues can be resolved by just adding an empty **init**.py file and making the dir a package, the package structure for imports seems to be better at relative imports only difference is instead of
`python -m unittest mytest/test.py`
you run it with
`python -m unittest mytest.test`
this may not fix the issue or you may not want to turn the dir into a module but its worth a try

Answer (score 0):

`unittest` can be run in several ways. You can code the test script to call `unittest.main()` and run it as `python mytest/test.py`. Or you can run `unittest` and have it import your tests as python modules. You are doing the second.

When you run `python -m unittest mytest/test.py`, `unittest` replaces "mytest/test.py" with "mytest.test" and imports that module. You could just as easily write `python -m unittest mytest.test`.

To get your modules to load, the `mytest` directory must be in the python path. That is a task that should normally be done in the environment outside of python.

If you are running a bash-like shell and you are in the parent of the mytest directory, you could do

```
PYTHONPATH=mytest:$PYTHONPATH python -m unittest test
```

Another good option is to make your entire project installable. You could then do `pip install --editable .` to run tests.

Better still, make a python virtual environment where you can run your tests.